# Python ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 when trying to implement covariance matrix from scratch

Tags: python, pandas, types, integer, covariance

I want to implement a covariance matrix from scratch. I got an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Admission_Predict.csv')

# Sanity check
print(f'N rows={len(df)}, M columns={len(df.columns)}')
df.head()

    GRE Score   TOEFL Score University Rating   SOP LOR CGPA    Research    Chance of Admit
0   337 118 4   4.5 4.5 9.65    1   0.92
1   324 107 4   4.0 4.5 8.87    1   0.76
2   316 104 3   3.0 3.5 8.00    1   0.72
3   322 110 3   3.5 2.5 8.67    1   0.80
4   314 103 2   2.0 3.0 8.21    0   0.65


mean = df.mean()
cov = {}


for j in range(len(mean)):
    df = df.sample(frac=1)
    total = 0
    for k in range(len(mean)):

        # Use Pearson correlation for interval variables
        terms = ((df.iloc[i, j] - mean.iloc[j]) * (df.iloc[i, k] - mean.iloc[k]) for i in range(len(mean)))
        covariance = sum(terms) / (len(mean) - 1)
        df_num = list(map(int, df))
        st_dev = statistics.pstdev(df_num)
        pearson = covariance[j, k] / (st_dev(j) * st_dev(k))

        # If feature k is already in dict, append Pearson. Else, apply feature k as a list object.
        if k in cov:
            cov[k].append(pearson)
        else:
            cov[k] = [pearson]

# Coerce the cov list into a dataframe
cov_df = pd.DataFrame(cov)

# rename the columns of the cov dataframe
col_dict = {}
for idx, col in enumerate(cov_df.columns):
    col_dict[idx] = col
cov_df = cov_df.rename(index=col_dict)

print(cov_df)


> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod2.py", line 17, in
> <module>
>     df_num = list(map(int, df)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GRE Score'
```

I've tried to cast the string using `astype` but it raised a type error.

```
df_num = df.astype(int)
```

> `TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator`

**Desired output**
I want to emulate the output from `pandas.corr()`

```
corr = df.corr()
print(corr)

                   GRE Score  TOEFL Score  ...  Research  Chance of Admit
GRE Score           1.000000     0.835977  ...  0.580391         0.802610
TOEFL Score         0.835977     1.000000  ...  0.489858         0.791594
University Rating   0.668976     0.695590  ...  0.447783         0.711250
SOP                 0.612831     0.657981  ...  0.444029         0.675732
LOR                 0.557555     0.567721  ...  0.396859         0.669889
CGPA                0.833060     0.828417  ...  0.521654         0.873289
Research            0.580391     0.489858  ...  1.000000         0.553202
Chance of Admit     0.802610     0.791594  ...  0.553202         1.000000

[8 rows x 8 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0


df.dtypes

GRE Score              int64
TOEFL Score            int64
University Rating      int64
SOP                  float64
LOR                  float64
CGPA                 float64
Research               int64
Chance of Admit      float64
dtype: object
```

Data source:
https://www.kaggle.com/adepvenugopal/graduate-admission-data?select=Admission_Predict.csv

Comment: Please provide the entire stacktrace

Comment: High possibility that your `dataframe` contains a string type that cannot be converted i.e. `1  .0` is not a valid integer.

Comment: @BernardL what's the solution?

Comment: @BernardL The `GRE score` column contained only integers.